# calculating the residue of $f(z)=\frac{\cot(z)\coth(z)}{z^3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-problem

Find the residue of

> $$f(z)=\frac{\cot(z)\coth(z)}{z^3}$$
>   at $z=0$.

I tried to use the Cauchy's residue formula, but the calculation is very complex. Can it be done in a simpler way?

Answer (score 2):

We use the Laurent series of $\cot$ and $\coth$ around $0$. See this [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html) .

If we take $$\coth (z)=\frac 1z+\frac z 3-\frac{z^3}{45}+o(z^4)$$
$$\cot(z)=\frac 1z-\frac z 3-\frac{z^3}{45}+o(z^4)$$

Now use these expressions to calculate $\frac{\cot z \coth z}{z^3}$, the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ is by definition the residue of that expression.